# jQuery creates element but leaves off title and placeholder

Tags: jquery

I am hitting my head on a walk trying to this this thing to work, I have an element being created dynamically on jQuery. It is passed several values, id, class and type, among others, when the element is added to the DOM only the id, type and class are applied to the element. some of the things I have tried:

first:

```
var markley = $('<input />', {
            type: 'text',
            id: settings.inputField.id,
            value: settings.inputField.value,
            class: settings.inputField.class
        });
 // james is the overarching div that markley is being added to.
    james.append(markley).attr({
            title: settings.inputField.title,
            placeholder: settings.inputField.placeholder
        });
```

second:

```
 var markley = $('<input />', {
            type: 'text',
            id: settings.inputField.id,
            value: settings.inputField.value,
            class: settings.inputField.class,
            title: settings.inputField.title,
            placeholder: settings.inputField.placeholder
        });
```

The html that is generated for this element:

I don't know why this is happening and all i seen to be able to fins is that it should be possible, and how to change pre-existing attributes, both of which will  not work for what I need. oh and the settings is an object passed with the properties that the function will use for the element creation and I have checked them and they are what they should be.

To note also that i tried to manually write the values into the html property of `markley`, and found that it too refused to work as expected... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it... in the line in `markley` where class was being set::

```
...
class:settings.inputField.class
...
```

the class is a key word, and this was causing the code to die here, the fix:

```
...
"class":settings.inputField.class
...
```